# What is the correct syntax for running a bash script as a step in EMR?

Tags: bash, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a bash script as a step after EMR completes bootstrapping. Following is my terraform code:

```
step { action_on_failure = "CONTINUE" 
name = "Setup Hadoop configuration" 
hadoop_jar_step { 
jar = "command-runner.jar" 
args = ["bash,-c,'cd /mnt; chmod +x ./userdata.sh; ./userdata.sh'"] 
}}
```

This isn't working and keeps on failing mentioning that No file found.
Are args correctly provided ? What about script-runner.jar?
Any help is highly appreciated. :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `command-runner.jar` you can execute many programs like bash script,
and you do not have to know its full path as was the case with `script-runner.jar`. It is recommended to use `command-runner.jar`.

EMR is in cluster mode, you do not know which nodes execute the shell script, so push it to S3  :

> ```
> {
>   "Name": "Setup Hadoop configuration",
>   "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
>  "HadoopJarStep": {
>     "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
>     "Args": [
>          "bash",
>          "-c",
>          " aws s3 cp s3://path_to_bucket_S3/userdata.sh .;
>           chmod +x userdata.sh;
>           ./userdata.sh args...;
>           rm userdata.sh "
>      ]
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I am trying to do something similar but get following error. Cannot run program "aws s3 cp s3://s3_bucket/install_python_libraries.sh .; chmod +x install_python_libraries.sh;          ./install_python_libraries.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

`command-runner.jar` can not execute remote file on s3. We have to use `script-runner.jar` to execute remote jar. This is how I did through Amazon UI.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please add a sample of sh that you provided as arguments to script runner jar?

Answer (score 1):

Snippet from AWS docs.

> The following is an example usage of command-runner.jar using the AWS
> CLI:
>
> ```
> aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-2AXXXXXXGAPLF --steps Name="Command Runner",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["spark-submit","Args..."]
> ```

Ref.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html

Answer (score 1):

create step-defn.json: (in S3 bucket or locally in EMR)

```
[{
"Name": "shell_script_that_needs_to_be_executed_as_emr_step",
"ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR",
"Jar":"command-runner.jar", 
"Args":["bash","-c","mkdir -p /tmp/script-for-s3-copy/; aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/some-blah-blah-shell-script.sh /tmp/script-for-s3-copy/;chmod -R 777 /tmp/script-for-s3-copy/*.sh;cd /tmp/script-for-s3-copy;sh some-blah-blah-shell-script.sh.sh"]
}]
```

Using bootstrap script download the Step definition in EMR's local folder (if the step-defn.json is stored in S3)

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-xxxxxxxxxxxx --steps file:///<folder_where_the_json_is_downloaded>/step-defn.json
```

Detailed Documentation  can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html