# Run script on all nodes after application installed on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-ssm

> Bootstrap actions run before Amazon EMR installs the applications that
> you specify when you create the cluster and before cluster nodes begin
> processing data. If you add nodes to a running cluster, bootstrap
> actions also run on those nodes in the same way. You can create custom
> bootstrap actions and specify them when you create your cluster.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

i need to patch the application (presto) after it is installed on all nodes. a few possible solutions are

- passwordless ssh, but for some security concern we disabled it.
- in the bootstrap schedule a cron job and check if the application is installed then act upon it.
- use [ssm](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/). but never really tried yet.

any idea?

[**Update**]
what actually has been done in our case is scheduling a background scripts (the `&`) in the bootstrap scripts which won't block bootstrap. inside the job, it will periodically check if the package is installed or not, if it is installed (e.g. `rpm -q presto`), then patch it.

Comment: this article shed some lights how the application installation works on EMR. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-deploying-custom-applications-with-apache-bigtop-and-amazon-emr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I believe you can use [EMR steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html) to do this. Here is a somewhat relevant [What is the correct syntax for running a bash script as a step in EMR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803980/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-running-a-bash-script-as-a-step-in-emr) description on how to use it.</s>

Update:

- You cannot use EMR steps since steps only [run on the master](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/bootstrap-step-emr/).

Comment: the problem with step is it runs only on master node but i need it to run on all nodes. or there is way to run a script on all nodes?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. I would try having a bootstrap action that would wait for presto install. The basic script would go to sleep for 3 min and then check if Presto is installed, if yes then patch else go to sleep again. It feels very wrong though. Maybe, another solution would be to install and patch Presto yourself withing a bootstrap action script. You can copy over presto configurations from the already configured EMR cluster to S3, then run the installer on the new EMR cluster and copy the configurations into the new EMR cluster. It would probably require some configuration updates.

Comment: To install Presto you could use EMR repositories and keys that are already on the EMR nodes. (Sorry, can't help beyond that)

Comment: yes. i checked the our codebase. actually there is already examples. what has been done is scheduling a background job - the `&`. this way bootstrap won't block on it and inside the job, it will check the evidence that an application is installed e.g. some configuration file.

Comment: I had to do this and documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875451/7091922